# Using Selenium/WebDriver and Python, how do I suppress the prompt to share my camera and microphone?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium in Python to automate a remote browser.  The browser needs access to its webcam and microphone.  When I navigate to a page that requests access, Firefox shows a pop-up window that asks "Would you like to share you camera and microphone with [host]?"

This window is not part of the browser's page, so it cannot be detected or controlled via Selenium.

This behavior is controlled by the media.navigator.permission.disabled option in Firefox's 'about:config' page.  If this option is set to 'true', then access to the camera should be granted automatically.

When I set that option to 'true', it eliminates the prompt only when I run Firefox manually.  When I run Firefox via Selenium, I still get the prompt.

How can I suppress this prompt, and have permission granted automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in Firefox profiles.  Selenium creates a new, temporary profile for each browser instance.  This profile is separate from the profile you use when you manually start Firefox.

Thus, when you set media.navigator.permission.disabled to 'true' in about:config, you do so only for your profile, and not for the profile that Selenium uses.

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Tell Selenium which existing profile to use.

   To do this, you must first determine which profile you are using.  To do this, close all instances of Firefox, then execute `firefox -p` to start the profile manager.  In most cases, you will see a single profile called `default`.

   Using this profile, navigate to `about:config`, and set the `media.navigator.permission.disabled` option to `true`.

   Then, when you start the Selenium standalone server, specify this profile:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=default
   ```

   This tells Selenium to use the `default` profile, which has the settings you want.
2. Create and configure a new profile for Selenium to use.

   Before you create the browser instance, you must create a Firefox profile and configure it to meet your needs:

   ```
   profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
   profile.set_preference ('media.navigator.permission.disabled', True)
   profile.update_preferences()
   ```

   Then specify this profile when you create the remote browser instance:

   ```
   firefox = selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver (command_executor=my_url, desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile=profile)
   ```

   Selenium will then use this profile, and you should not be prompted for permission to access the camera.

   Note that this method takes more time than the first method.

Comment: Either you *very* quickly found the answer to your own problem or you are intending this to be a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use options:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", True)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```