# RSpec system tests with selenium - Allow access to Camera

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

In my Ruby on Rails 6.0, I'm trying to test a page that has access to the camera. 
The problem is that when I visit this page, there is a popup message that I should permit to use the camera. 
This is breaking my tests, how can I click allow to that popup or somehow give permissions to the camera to Selenium WebDrvier.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Firefox it looks like you can set a profile option:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310797/using-selenium-webdriver-and-python-how-do-i-suppress-the-prompt-to-share-my-ca  Other browsers should have a similar profile option you can set and use in Selenium.  eg: create a new profile, set the option.  Send that profile as argument when launching driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use fake-web cam on mozilla firefox using selenium java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234576/how-to-use-fake-web-cam-on-mozilla-firefox-using-selenium-java)